# How can I propagate html strings in a Yew application?

Tags: html-encode, yew

Let's say a Yew app currently uses,

```
{ "<strong>foo</strong>" }
```

How can I emit that in such a fashion that it's not safely encoded as HTML, and instead rendered by the client as HTML and sent out unencoded.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported. Follow the proposal on GitHub (with a mention of the workarounds)

https://github.com/yewstack/yew/issues/182